# POI save failure

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

No matter how I open an xlsx, either populated or blank file, with the code below I get the errors second below shortened. My pom dependencies are third below.  I am nonplussed.  Do I downgrade the dependencies?  The HSSF code works fine.

```
    try {
        in = currentFile.getInputStream();
        try {
            pkg00 = OPCPackage.open(in);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentWb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg00);  //need to close with OPCPackage pkg00.close()
        //currentWb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(in);
        currentSheet = currentWb.getSheetAt(0);
        cleanWb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        cleanSheet = cleanWb.createSheet();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the save code:

```
try {
    String path = createPath(markingDir,currentName,fileNum,null,null).toString();
    pkg00.save(new FileOutputStream(new File(createPath(markingDir,currentName,fileNum,null,null).toString())));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//createSerialFileName(markingDir, currentName, fileNum, cleanWb, null);
fileNum++;
filesProcessed++;
```

> Wed Jul 01 15:30:35 EDT 2020 There was an unexpected error
> (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider: Provider
> com.spire.ms.charsets.CharsetProvider not found
> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
> java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider: Provider
> com.spire.ms.charsets.CharsetProvider not found

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I am unable to recreate your error using the same dependencies as you. The only difference is how I am getting my `InputStream` - which is directly from a file: `InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/file/in.xlsx"));`. How are you getting your input stream?

Comment: That is positive.  It is from an MultipartFile upload.  Exact same technique as with the HSSF data.  Very odd.  Same exact error with either save technique even with an empty file.  How could the charset be specified or read differently in MultpartFile for xls vs xlsx?  You said it work as is then I should not need to run it through POIFSFilesystem.  Of course difference is you are reading from disk and I cant it off a webpage.

Comment: Can you use your file input stream with a workbook factory? `Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(currentFile.getInputStream());`. Referenced from [here](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream).

Comment: The error tells that a special `CharsetProvider` cannot be found. What code line throws that error? And btw.: Yor save code is not correct. Only calling `OPCPackage.save` is not sufficient. `XSSFWorkbook.write` should be used instead. This calls `onSave` for each `PackagePart` and commits the prperties part before saving the `OPCPackage`.

Comment: Same error.  Is the CharsetProvider not specified in HSSFWorkbook.  Others must be using MultipartFile uploads of xlsx.  I will try it with lower versions of POI.  Yes also open a file from the local filesystem and resave it as control.

Comment: ...shaking his head....  You will not believe this but same error.  Okay I will put together a minimal [not]working example and post on github and let other see. Yes 3.17, yes HSSF work, sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved over to the hetrogenous ".ss." workbook and sheet in 4.12 and it saved wop.  As a note that may be helpful, in my specific data case an xlsx with a blank line does not even add a null row but skips the row increment so to duplicate exactly, in my case, you would need to track the row number and where there is a missing increment explicitly insert a row.  This is impt to the parsing as it breaks on the first blank cell in a column.  fth.